# How to add a static library to the framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

The keyFramework uses encrypt.a

```
keyFramework.framework 

[Link Binary With Libraries] 
encrypt.a 
Foundation.framework 
...
```

In what form is "encrypt.a" included in the framework when compiling?

I do not think "encrypt.a" is included in the framework.

Comment: You should let the target app to link the static library instead of your framework, not bundled it into your framework

Comment: oh no... thank you :)